# Search file in directories and return value

Tags: php, function, recursion

I running this script for search file name inside different directories, the problem it´s don´t show me the return value, only works if use print or echo inside function, i think the problem it´s return value with recursive function

**My Code :**

```php
function search_file_dir($ruta, $search)
{
    $dir = opendir("" . $ruta . "");
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (is_dir("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "")) {
                $dir_out = "" . $file . "";
                search_file_dir("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "", "" . $search . "");
            }
            if (is_file("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "")) {

                if (substr($file, 0, -4) == $search) {
                    $ruta_end = "" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "";

                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $ruta_end;
}
```

**And works calling this**

```
echo search_file_dir("gallery","flower.png")
```

By this my question because how use return value in this case for show the value if function it´s recursive, the funtions works fine and search all, in all kind of directories but don´t works return

**Thank´s in advanced
Best Regards**

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning the search result on each recursion.

The function returns `$ruta_end` when your `is_file()` condition is true.

But when it is `is_dir()` there is an empty response because `$ruta_end` has not been assigned a value.
This makes the function provide a valid response for root dirs (*as mentioned by you*) but when searching in sub directories the response will be empty.

Basically do this `$ruta_end = search_file_dir(...)`

```
function search_file_dir($ruta, $search)
{
    $dir = opendir("" . $ruta . "");
    while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
        if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
            if (is_dir("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "")) {
                $dir_out = "" . $file . "";
                $ruta_end = search_file_dir("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "", "" . $search . "");
            }
            if (is_file("" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "")) {

                 ## Why are you using a substr -> to remove extension?
                 ## If yes then it will not work on extensions like 'docx` (length more than 3)
                 ## Use pathinfo() instead
                 ## In your question the search term is flower.png so why remove extension in the first place. But I assume that is a typo

                if (substr($file, 0, -4) == $search) { 
                    $ruta_end = "" . $ruta . "/" . $file . "";

                }
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    return $ruta_end;
}
```